# Select and replace string from first occurence of defined character till last occurence

Tags: sed, grep

I want print usernames and real names from /etc/passwd in this format: **johnwick3=John Wick**

The entries in /etc/passwd looks like this:

> johnwick3:x:15905:10513:John Wick:/home/john/folder:/bin/bash

The numbers are different on every line.

So I extracted everything till the end of name with:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep -o -P '(?<=).*(?=:/home)'
```

which gives me:

> johnwick3:x:15905:10513:John Wick

How can I extract everything between first colon till last colon and replace it with **"="** ?

Comment: Just `cut` and `tr`

Comment: May be this awk `awk -F: -v OFS== '{gsub(/^[^:]*:|:[^:]*$/, ""); $1=$1} 1' /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should be just enough for some displaying:

```
grep '/home' /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1,5 | tr ':' '='
```

But in a script I would:

```
awk -F: -v OFS== '$6 ~ "^/home/"{print $1,$5}' /etc/passwd
```